# How to determine when all methods are finished?

Tags: objective-c, methods, method-call

I have RootViewController where I create my MainViewDownload instance and call method of that instance.

```
MainViewDownload *download = [[MainViewDownload alloc] init];
[download loadMainViewImages];
```

How can I know when loadMainViewImages is finished ? I only call loadMainViewImages from RootViewController but loadMainViewImages calls another method inside MainViewDownload class (lets say method2), and that method2 calls again method3. So, is there a way to know when loadMainViewImages is finished (actually when method3 is finished since its last called).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not multithreading, i.e. starting a method that runs on a separate thread from `loadMainViewImages`, then the methods will be executed sequentially. So once the `loadMainViewImages` returns you can be sure everything "in it" was executed. This is how methods work.

**EDIT** for better formatting of the comments:

MainViewDownload.h

```
@protocol MainViewDownloadDelegate;

@interface MainViewDownload
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSObject<MainViewDownloadDelegate> *delegate;
@end

@protocol MainViewDownloadDelegate
- (void)downloadDidFinish:(MainViewDownload *)download;
@end
```

MainViewDownload.m

```
@implementation MainViewDownload

- (void)someMethodThatDownloadsStuff_OrIsCalledAfterTheDownload {
    ...
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(downloadDidFinish:)]) {
        [self.delegate downloadDidFinish:self];
    }
}

@end
```

RootViewController.h

```
@interface RootViewController <MainViewDownloadDelegate>
...
@end
```

RootViewController.m

```
@implementation
...
- (void)downloadDidFinish:(MainViewDownload *)download {
    // hide the download view here.
}
@end
```

Make sure to set the delegate of the download view to the root view controller.

Comment: is there a way to block before loadMainViewImages is finished ?

Comment: What do you mean? Just add something to the end of it. But that will be the same as if you put that code after `loadMainViewImages` in your root view controller.

Comment: So, I need [download loadMainViewImages] and when loading is done, then remove LoadingView screen for example. But if I just add that line below it wont wait loadMainViewImages to be finished

Comment: This is precisely the case where you might want to consider using a delegate. Add a protocol to your `MainViewDownload` called `MainViewDownloadDelegate` or similar. Add a method `- (void)downloadFinished:(MainViewDownload *)download;` to it. Add a weak delegate property to MainViewDownload that implements this protocol: `@property (nonatomic, weak) NSObject<MainViewDownloadDelegate> *delegate;`. Extend `RootViewController` to implement the protocol. `@interface RootViewController <MainViewDownladDelegate>` and implement the method in `RootViewController` to do what you want adter a download.

Comment: Now you just need to send that message to your delegate when the download is done: `if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(downloadFinished:)]) [self.delegate downloadFinished:self];`

Comment: Thanks. Just one more question. How can I add view over navigationcontroller ? I want to add subview (image saying loading.. or something) over whole navigation view, but when I add subview its always added below navigationBar.

Comment: I recommend asking that as a separate question. But there is a good question you'll find a solution if you search, as this is a common problem.